# Does anyone know of a replacement method for setFixed() that returns a number?

Tags: javascript

Working with the method setFixed() returns a string in most browsers, but sometimes I need to set a number to a fixed set of decimal places and I need it to stay a number.

Plus I would like to be able to access it from the number object in javascript as part of the prototype object.

And it should ALWAYS return a number as a result instead of a string.

Anyone know of a good article or method to use?

I would also like a way to control whether it rounds up, down, or uses standard rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an article on doing just that here:

http://exoboy.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/the-problems-with-tofixed-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.prototype.decimals=function(n){
     return +(this.toFixed(n));
}
```

Comment: interesting, what is the + for? I am not familiar with that usage.

Comment: Applying the unary plus operator like that changes the String into a Number.

Comment: @stepehen thanks for the explanation, I usually just coerce it with Number(). But your shorthand is good to know a well.